How to read prop value inside pseudo element in styled-components?
I've been trying to read the value which was passed down by a prop. I'm trying to read it inside ::before pseudo element:
Button/index.tsx
export const Button: FC<ButtonProps> = ({children, ...props}) => {
  return 
    <_Button $textValue="TEST" {...props}>
      <p style={{color: 'red'}}>{children}</p>
    </_Button>
};

Button/styles.ts
import styled from "styled-components";

const colors = {
  black: 'var(--color-black)',
  white: 'var(--color-white)'
};

type ButtonColors = "black" | "white";

export type ButtonProps = {
  $color?: ButtonColors;
  $background?: ButtonColors;
}

export const _Button = styled.button<ButtonProps & {$textValue: string}>`
  color: ${(props) => props.$color && colors[props.$color]};
  background: ${(props) => props.$background && colors[props.$background]};
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: none;
  padding: 14px 24px; 
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: relative;
  &::before {
    content: ${(props) => props.$textValue};
    width: 2rem;
    height: 2rem;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 2rem;
    color: green;
  }
`;

_Button.defaultProps = {
  $color: "white",
  $background: "black"
}

However, it does not appear in the DOM (it doesn't get rendered).
There is no ::before element seen

How can I do it? Is it even possible to read a value like that?
